# Getting error in watch app installation - application install failed: Invalid Application Stub

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I am getting following error in system console while installing watch app on device.
"application install failed: Invalid Application Stub"

Watchkit extesion and watch app deplyment target is set iOS 8.2.
I have also matched project setting to "watchkit project configuration reference"

Comment: It is iOS 8.4 on phone and watch OS 1 on watch.

Comment: Check respective provisioning profiles and bundle identifiers for App, Watchkit extension and iWatch App.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have verifed my project setings with "watchkit project configuration reference" document.

Comment: It works fine when we install app directly from xcode.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it sufficed to do a 
`rm -rf ~/Library/developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`
and if using Carthage,
`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem myself after lots of frustration..

This error is more related to ipa making process than any project settings..

Avoid using older xcodes just to make ipa from the archive created using latest xcode as sometimes we don't have permission to export build.

You can use xcodebuild command to create ipa from archive and resolve this error,but can't make it to appstore as xocdebuild also come with a bug that it doesn't create support directories for watchapp ( WatchKitSupport ) and swift ( SwiftSupport ).However with this ipa, application will get installed on Apple Watch without any errors..

I also done a research to find a valid command which would make valid ipa but other options also have the same issues. Eg xcrun

Solution to this is make this folder structure by yourself and create ipa.

These link may help to get proper script to export valid ipa..
[How to generate .ipa file from command line with watchkit app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522191/how-to-generate-ipa-file-from-command-line-with-watchkit-app)

[Binary Rejection - Invalid Watchkit Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973149/binary-rejection-invalid-watchkit-support)